# Disable form fields in Sulu's admin frontend after the entity has been persisted

Tags: sulu

I'd like to connect the key of a category in the [Sulu CMS](https://sulu.io/) with specific business logic. But therefore the key must not be changeable in the admin area. Is there a way to disable a form field once the entity is persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to override any form configuration by creating a file with the same name and the same `<key>` in the `config/forms/` directory of your project. In case of the category details form, create a `config/forms/category_details.xml` file with `<key>category_details</key>` containing only the properties you want to override, in your case the `<property name="key">`. You can omit the other properties, because all the form configurations with the same key will be merged together. Then you can use a `disabledCondition` to configure when this property should be disabled and when it should be possible to edit, in your case something like `disaledCondition="!!id"`, because then the property is only editable, as long as it doesn't have an id, which is only the case when you create a new category. You probably also want to add the `mandatory="true"` attribute, if your application depends on the key of a category. So the whole file should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/form-1.0.xsd"
>
    <key>category_details</key>

    <properties>
        <property name="key" type="text_line" mandatory="true" disabledCondition="!!id">
            <meta>
                <title>sulu_admin.key</title>
            </meta>
        </property>
    </properties>
</form>
```